# Centos6 Apache configure SUEXEC wrapper

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, centos6, httpd, suexec

On a Centos 6 trying to upgrade to a specific apache version (from 2.2.24 to 2.2.25) from source since yum doesn't have the right version I need (or the very least I can't find the repo for it) and I ran into an issue with suexec not being able to run my virtual host.

I copied all the config over from my working older apache version, modified the httpd.conf to reflect the new location and the new port. Currently I still have my .24 apache running on port 80 in /etc/httpd and I am trying to configure my .25 apache which is in /usr/local/apache2 and whenever I start up the new apache I get:

```
Warning: SuexecUserGroup directive requires SUEXEC wrapper.
```

Reading up a bit up on suexec I see that it needs a wrapper and I am completely oblivious as where to go after having my entire apache compiled.

Is suexec wrapper something you can add on after ./config, make, make install?

I am new to working with apache so any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm not sure if I should try to delete the entire instance of the newer apache and try to reconfigure & make it, but at the same time I'm not sure how to delete only the newer apache without messing up the currently configured version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build apache yourself and you want the suexec wrapper compiled with it, you need to add it before compiling to the configure options: `--enable-suexec`.

Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html#install

If you just compile and install again, only the new apache should be overwritten.